# FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived never gets triggered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

For some reason the methode TokenReceived never gets called on my Android device.
The script looks like this:

```
public class FCM : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += TokenReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
   
    }

    public void MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Message received: " + e.Message);
    }

    public void TokenReceived(object sender, TokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Token received: "+ e.Token);
        text.text = "received a token";
    }
}
```

I made sure that i have the latest Firebase SDK and i am also able to send a push notification to every device(via firebase console). Now i wanna have the methode TokenReceived triggered, so i can safe that token in my database. I also followed all the steps from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client. Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived` doesn't seem to work on some Android devices. Thankfully you can get the FCM Token manually by calling `FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync()` like this:

```
public string fcmToken = "";

void Start()
{
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
    FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        fcmToken = task.Result;
    });
}
```